# What does "Vector" mean in nodes as input and output?

Tags: node-editor

What does Vector mean in nodes input and output in Blender?

Please explain in simple words

Comment: Vector refers to something that is located in 3D (for instance a point on a surface or volume) or 2D space (i.e a point on a texture). A vector is characterized by 3 values usually named X, Y and Z in 3D space.

Comment: Vector is a class that contain 3 or 4 number. In Blender, `Vector` is a python class under `mathutils` which provide a lot of useful function to deal with 3D math problem. See the [DOC here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.html?#mathutils.Vector)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Vector" mean in nodes as input and output? Please explain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242857/what-does-vector-mean-in-nodes-as-input-and-output-please-explain)