# What does "Vector" mean in nodes as input and output? Please explain

Tags: node-editor

What does Vector mean in nodes input and output in Blender?

Comment: it is made to send and receive 3D informations (what happens on X, Y and Z)

Comment: if you don't know what a vector is....maybe you should learn first some basic math....and a node is just a function, which you give a/some values and it returns a/some values. That's all. So basically...i do not understand your question!?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152485/what-does-vector-mean-in-nodes-as-input-and-output              this exact question has already been asked

Comment: Related question [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33915/107598)

Comment: It's just x, y, and z-coordinates (which may actually represent x, y, and z-coordinates or angles in radians). In some nodes, it represents a single point of an object (like origin), in others it may represent all points of an object (I think this moment is cumbersome).

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Well as the name implies, it's a vector, a 3 dimensional vector with 3 components `x`, `y` and `z`. It's different from, for example, the scalar (grey) socket which is a scalar value or the yellow socket which is a color value (consisting actually of 4 components R, G, B, and A or 3 if we have no Alpha).

You can see the vector socket as 3 grey sockets combined and the color socket as 4 grey sockets combined (3 without Alpha).

You can use the `Converter>Combine XYZ`, `Converter>Combine RGB`, `Converter>Combine RGBA` to convert from scalar value to vector, RGB or RGBA respectively.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can also get each individual components of a vector, RGB or RGBA color by using their `Converter>Separate` counterparts :

[image]
[image]
[image]

The rule of thumb is that you should (almost) never plug two sockets of different colors to each other unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: That's a good point that the yellow node can have 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) components.